# Как сделать чат на WebSocket + php?

Tags: php, websocket

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, работающий код чата на WebSocket+php (либо на другой технологии, не выполняя каждые несколько секунд запросов для получения новых сообщений). Что-то готового понятного примера так и не нашёл.

Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательная библиотека `Ratchet` для работы с веб-сокетами.

Answer (score 0):

Сам штудирую эту тему, начал с вот [этого базового видео-урока / LessonFirst на YouTube].[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m14Mag7r0zk)

Comment: А потом по эти статьям:

 1. [Делаем вебсокеты на PHP с нуля / Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/)
 2. [Делаем вебсокеты на PHP с нуля. Часть 2. IPC / Хабрахабр](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ifree/blog/210228/)
 3. [Простой веб-сокет на PHP или веб сокеты с абсолютного 0 / Егор и Артур Петуховские](http://petukhovsky.com/simple-web-socket-on-php-from-very-start/)

Comment: @IncreMan Я уже за это время понял, что на php не напишешь нормально. Перешёл сперва на golang,а сейчас на C# Asp.Net Core. Советую последний

Comment: Господа модераторы, так как я написал что сам штудирую тему, соответственно не могу написать готового ответа должного качества. По этому приложил ссылки на найденную мной информацию, которая для меня стала полезной в изучении этой темы, но я ещё в процессе. Согласен полностью с тем фактом что в случае удаления видео/статей ссылка будет недействительна и ответ потеряет свою актуальность. По этому наверное правильней будет удалить.